# Can I use role and aria attributes in xhtml 1.0

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c, wcag

I am using XHTML 1.0 for a website. I want to make it accessible so I want add the "role" and "aria" attributes in my markup. Will this in anyway help Assistive technologies better interpret my website or are these attributes only meant for HTML5?

Comment: WAI-ARIA was first created for XHTML 1.1. So you can't validate it with XHTML 1.0. But if you serve it as `text/html` browsers will treat it the same as HTML5 anyway.

Comment: Do you mean if I serve my <html> like this -
<html content="text/html> ?

Comment: No. I mean the file should be sent with an HTTP header of `Content-Type:text/html`. But web servers will normally do that for you anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I did some testing and I can confidently report that it WORKS!

Sure the markup showed up as invalid but the screen readers were easily able to pickup the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need to use XHTML1.0, the WAI-ARIA group has [released an unofficial XHTML1.0+ARIA Doctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/appendices#xhtml_dtd) that will allow you write relatively conforming code with the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+ARIA 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/schemata/xhtml-aria-1.dtd">
```

Comment: This helps but still does not answer my question properly. What if I can not change the Doctype, can I still use these attributes and will they work regardless of the markup becoming invalid?

Comment: If you can't change the doctype you are in a hard place. You either write non-validating code, or you can't add the required ARIA tags.

Comment: Just an addition, this article describes in a little more detail why you can't use aria with xhtml or html4 to this day. Basically, supporting ARIA will mean updating DTD's which are part of spec. http://www.powermapper.com/blog/w3-aria-why-doesnt-it-validate/